# "Cannot open input file 'libcrypto.lib'" while installing libtorrent C++ library

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, openssl, libtorrent

I am attempting to install the libtorrent C++ library (cloned from GitHub repository) on Windows 11 with `OpenSSL 1.1.1i` installed and Visual Studio 2022.

Invoking b2 in my libtorrent source folder is returning the error `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libcrypto.lib'`.

The file `libcrypto.lib` definitely exists in `C:\Users\Me\openssl` and `C:\Users\Me\openssl` is in my PATH. Installation was running fine until this point.

My steps were:

```
$ set LIB="C:\Users\Me\openssl";%LIB%
$ set INCLUDE="C:\Users\Me\openssl\include";%INCLUDE%
$ set BOOST_ROOT=c:\boost_1_80_0
$ set BOOST_BUILD_PATH=%BOOST_ROOT%\tools\build
$ cd "C:\Users\Me\libtorrent"
$ b2
```

The last step returns:

> ...updating 3 targets... msvc.link.dll
> bin\msvc-14.3\debug\cxxstd-14-iso\threading-multi\torrent-rasterbar.dll
> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libcrypto.lib'
>
> call "bin\standalone\msvc\msvc-14.3\msvc-setup.bat"  >nul  link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO
> @"bin\msvc-14.3\debug\cxxstd-14-iso\threading-multi\torrent-rasterbar.dll.rsp"
> ...failed msvc.link.dll
> bin\msvc-14.3\debug\cxxstd-14-iso\threading-multi\torrent-rasterbar.dll
> bin\msvc-14.3\debug\cxxstd-14-iso\threading-multi\torrent.lib
> bin\msvc-14.3\debug\cxxstd-14-iso\threading-multi\torrent-rasterbar.pdb...
> ...removing
> bin\msvc-14.3\debug\cxxstd-14-iso\threading-multi\torrent-rasterbar.pdb
> ...failed updating 3 targets...

Edit: Fixed a typo

Comment: `set LIB="C:\Users\Me\openssl;%LIB%` is this a typo / copy paste error or are you missing a "

Comment: According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1181?view=msvc-170), the error is caused because it does not exist or the path cannot be found, please double check that your file path is entered correctly.

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo. Fixed in question body.

Comment: All paths are correct. I have moved `libcrypto.lib` to `C:\Users\Me\libtorrent` and still getting the same error. Same error also when running `python setup.py build`.

Comment: ***LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libcrypto.lib'*** When the linker in msvc says it can not open a library.lib file it's usually 1 or more of the following: 1) The library is not named what you told it or the path you gave to the linker folders is not correct, 2) You are mixing 32 and 64 bit or 3) The library file is corrupt.

Comment: Thank you. By moving the file around I eventually got it to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by copying `libcrypto.lib` to LIB path specified in `user-config.jam`.